# Is there a way to run with_items loops in parallel in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm running Ansible 2.2, but can upgrade if it helps.

I saw [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12086) and was pretty excited, but it doesn't seem to be in this (or any) version of Ansible documentation.

The problem I'm trying to solve is I've got 1000 users that I need to manage on a Centos box.

It takes quite a while to run this task serially.  And even more annoying, everything shows up as changed because the "expires" command on the user module always marks the thing as changed.

[this](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html) also looked promising, but it took the same amount of time to run each command in the with_items loop and didn't go any faster (I never bothered to wait long enough to get to the end).

Skipping tasks is fast now (a lot faster than it was in Ansible 2.0), if I can't figure out how to make this work in parallel, I think I'll go back and figure out how to skip pointless tasks and if all else fails, I'll write my own module.  But it seems like I should be able to do all this faster in Ansible.

---

This is what I want to run in parallel,  `host_authorizations` is a list of usernames and other data.

```
  - name: Create/modify OS user accounts
    user: name={{ item.username }} group=sshusers shell=/bin/bash home="/home/selinux-modules/{{ item.username }}" state=present expires={{item.expiredate|default(omit)}}
    with_items: "{{ host_authorizations }}"
    tags: full_maintenance
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet. Otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: @030 there's a snippet, I guess it helps a bit for context.  I'm more interested conceptually if there really is a way to run tasks (in a loop) in parallel on the same host.  I know I could do a ton of individual things with async, but not so much with with_items.

Comment: So basically if 1000 users have to be created then it should be finished as fast as creating just one user. Interesting, why not using something like LDAP?

Comment: @030 that's what I want. These aren't human users, so I need to add public keys for all the enabled users (and expire the rest). LDAP would have worked for part of it, but not the public key part, still I think that would have worked for the annoying part, so that's a good suggestion.

Comment: It was just an idea, never implemented. 

`ISSUE TYPE
Feature Idea`

Comment: Seriously, you're heading toward a path of pain, I don't think anyone handle more than a dozen of accounts with local account base, as soon as the number of users grow, I assume everyone move to a centralized accounting system, usualy some ldap backend (could be active directory) and then set the expiry time and public key as attributes of this central base then use things like sss_ssh_authorizedkeys to let the ssh server get the authorized keys from this central base.

Comment: @tensibai, that's what ansible is for! These aren't real user accounts, they're for automation and driven by a postgres database that I generate a dynamic inventory off of.

Comment: I disagree this is what ansible is for (hint being it doesn't do bulk user creation/management). I stand by the point that accounts should not be managed on local account bases at large volume (fact they are not human accounts is irrelevant to the problem anyway)

Comment: I've tried the third option with a list of locales to be created using the `community.general.locale_gen` module. I belive it went a little faster than usual, but not that much. I noticed that there was only one `locale_def` process displayed by `top`. May it be that it would take much more advantage of multiple cores or vCPUs if more processes could be spawned, one for each item in the loop? Maybe that would require more connections to be opened from the Ansible Controller to the host?

Answer (score 32):

As @webKnja mentioned this is possible with `async` mode. I have recently discovered it myself and learned that you can use it in 3 different ways depending on your needs.

1. **Execute and poll** the results, notice the `poll:5`, This will poll the results every 5 seconds. You may save some time with this method.

   ```
    - name: My long runing task
      some_module_name:
        ip: "{{item.fabric}}"
        username: "{{user}}"
        password: "{{password}}"
        secret: "{{secret}}"
      loop: "{{zoning_list}}"
      register: _alias_vc_0
      async: 60
      poll: 5
   ```
2. **Fire and forget** `poll: 0`, This is very quick option since Ansible it's just shooting out those tasks. The down side is that we don't know what was the outcome of the task i.e. `changed: True/False`. Of course it's a downside if you care about the feedback ;).

   ```
    name: My long runing task
    some_module_name:
      ip: "{{item.fabric}}"
      username: "{{user}}"
      password: "{{password}}"
      secret: "{{secret}}"
    loop: "{{zoning_list}}"
    register: _alias_vc_0
    async: 60
    poll: 0
   ```
3. **Fire and forget with `async_status`**, the syntax for the task is the same as example **2** whowever it will require additional task `async_status`. This is my favorite since it's relatively fast (faster then normal looping or the `execute and poll`) and allows you to capture the feedback although will need to deal with new `register` for your `async_task`.

`retries: 20` -- how many attempts before failing.

`delay: 2` -- how many second to wait between polls.

```
    - name: My long runing task
      some_module_name:
        ip: "{{item.fabric}}"
        username: "{{user}}"
        password: "{{password}}"
        secret: "{{secret}}"
      loop: "{{zoning_list}}"
      register: _alias_vc_0
      async: 60
      poll: 0


    - name: Wait for My long running task to finish
      async_status:
        id: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
        #jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}" # ansible version > 2.8
      register: _jobs_alias_vc_0
      retries: 20
      delay: 2
      until: _jobs_alias_vc_0.finished
      loop: "{{_alias_vc_0.results}}"
```

**A word of caution**, depending on the task yo may not be able to use the `async` option. I had examples where I was interacting with system which was not able to handle multiple requests for the same resource. I found `async` option best working if I have to perform the same task across multiple hosts. That's where I was able to "save" the most time.

Since you posted the link to Ansible documentation in the question I'm not going to do that.

Comment: @chicks you might want to change the `poll` value to 0 in example 3.  

This is an amazing explanation!! Thnx.

Comment: @DebanjanBasu Anybody can make suggested edits.  I might be the one who approves it in the review queues, but you should get credit for the edit itself.

Comment: One character edits aren't allowed sadly! :(

Comment: Option 3 works great, thanks! One comment though: as of at least Ansible 2.8, `async_status` requires `jid`, not `id`.

Comment: Although correct, this method fails when you enable `jinja2_native` unless Ansible includes a [fix](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/79951). Unfortunately, Ansible, up to and including v2.14.3, does not have it.

Comment: "I found async option best working if I have to perform the same task across multiple hosts" -- wouldn't that depend on the task? If a simple task is run against a group of hosts for example, it already runs in parallel, i.e. it will start the task on all hosts and wait for all of them to complete. My understanding is that the greatest benefit of async is when running multiple commands within the same task, that otherwise would block eachother.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to achieve this using `async` mode. Please find some references for how to do this below.

Refs:

- http://toroid.org/ansible-parallel-dispatch
- https://blog.crisp.se/2018/01/27/maxwenzin/how-to-run-ansible-tasks-in-parallel

```
---

- name: Run tasks in parallel
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Pretend to create instances
      command: "sleep {{ item }}"  # Instead of calling a long running operation at a cloud provider, we just sleep.
      with_items:
        - 6
        - 8
        - 7
      register: _create_instances
      async: 600  # Maximum runtime in seconds. Adjust as needed.
      poll: 0  # Fire and continue (never poll)

    - name: Wait for creation to finish
      async_status:
        jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: _jobs
      until: _jobs.finished
      delay: 5  # Check every 5 seconds. Adjust as you like.
      retries: 10  # Retry up to 10 times. Adjust as needed.
      with_items: "{{ _create_instances.results }}"
```

Comment: While those links may answer the question if they come to break there's nothing left in your answer for future readers, please try to showcase how this would help solving the problem with your own words/exemple and leave the links for more detailed informations only.

Comment: yeah, I can't mark this as the answer until A.) I test it and B.) relevant code is placed in here.  But thank you for pointing me in this direction nevertheless.

Comment: Sorry, I was it hurry :)

Comment: @PeterTurner I believe the code has been added since.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: No, as of now Ansible can't run loops in parallel.

I'd use [`newusers`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/newusers) instead, which is made for bulk user creation. Create a file with all users in it, copy it over to the host, and run `newusers /path/to/user/list` in a `command` or `shell` task.

For example:

```
- name: Create multiple users
  shell: newusers /path/to/user/list && touch /path/to/user/ansible-users-added
  args:
    creates: /path/to/user/ansible-users-added
```